# Data posting server gets error in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here i got a token number from api like as shown here `"210"` and it is saving using userdefaults but when i tried to retrieve data from the userdefaults then it is returning `"\"210\""` like this why it is adding slashes and  quotes can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

here is the code for posting key

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer \(self.CustomerToken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        print(self.CustomerToken!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
            let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            self.keyStatusCode = status
            print(responseString!)
            self.customerCartIdNumber = responseString!
            self.customerCartIdNumber = responseString!
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.customerCartIdNumber, forKey: "CustomerLoginNumber")
            print(self.customerCartIdNumber!)
            print(responseString!)
```

here is the code for getting key

```
 let customerId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "CustomerLoginNumber")
            self.customerCartId = customerId!
            print(customerId!)
```

here is the code for posting

```
func customerAddToCartItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(cartApi: String){
        let url = URL(string: cartApi)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let cartNumber = customerCartId?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
        let parameters : [String: Any] = ["cartItem":
            [
                "quote_id": "\(customerCartId!)",
                "sku": "\(itemCode!)",
                "qty":"1"
            ]
        ]
        print(customerCartId)
        print(parameters)
        print(cartNumber)
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer \(self.customerKeyToken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Show the code where you are saving to user defaults.

Comment: i had edited my post and added code for saving to userdefaults @MikeTaverne

Comment: Is your service returning the token number as a bare string, "210"?

Comment: yes returning as a string `"210"` @MikeTaverne